# setTimeout and .click for images HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an animated gif that doesn't have a loop. I want to display images on top of the gif after about 6 seconds. I would like some images to have an onlick event that scrolls to a section of the page(embedded code), some that displays box/container, and others that open a link. I have figured out how to place the images on top of the gif but I can't seem to get the setTimeout or onclick functions to work. I am using weebly so I am placing the script in the html.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" defer>
        setTimeout(function(){
            document.querySelector(".contact-icon").style.display = 'inline-block';},6000)
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" defer>
$(".contact-icon").click(function() {
            $('html,body').animate({
                scrollBottom: $(".contact").offset().bottom},
                'slow');});
    </script>
</head>
<div id="tablet-container">
            <img src="/files/theme/tablet.gif" height="645" width="960"    style="padding:65px;"/>
            <div id="contact-icon-container">
                <a href="#" class="sprite contact-icon"></a>    
            </div>
            <div id="gallery-icon-container">
                <a href="#" class="sprite gallery-icon"></a>
            </div>
            <div id="gmail-icon-container">
                <a href="#" class="sprite Communcation-gmail-icon"></a>
            </div>
            <div id="piechart-icon-container">
                <a href="#" class="sprite piechart-icon"></a>
            </div>
            <div id="linkedin-icon-container">
                <a href="#" class="sprite LinkedIn_logo_initials"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

```
<css>
.sprite {
background: url(sprites.png) no-repeat;
display:inline-block;
}
.Communication-gmail-icon{
background-position: 0 0;
width: 66px;
height: 66px;
}
.Communication-gmail-icon:hover, .Communication-gmail-icon:active{
background-position: -96px 0;
width: 66px;
height: 66px;
}
.contact-icon{
background-position: 0 -77px ;
width: 66px;
height: 66px;
}
.contact-icon:hover, .contact-icon:active{
background-position: -95px -75px ;
width: 66px;
height: 66px;
}
.gallery-icon{
background-position: 0 -322px ;
width: 66px;
height: 66px;
}
.gallery-icon:hover, .gallery-icon:active{
background-position: -97px -321px ;
width: 66px;
height: 66px;
}
.LinkedIn_logo_initials{
background-position: -200px -83px ;
width: 66px;
height: 66px;
}
.LinkedIn_logo_initials:hover, .LinkedIn_logo_initials:active{
background-position: -295px -83px ;
width: 66px;
height: 66px;
}
.piechart-icon{
background-position: -198px -324px ;
width: 66px;
height: 66px;
}
.piechart-icon:hover, piechart-icon:active{
background-position: -292px -324px ;
width: 66px;
height: 66px;
}
/*Positioning for icons on top of Gif*/
#contact-icon-container{
position:relative;
top:-280px;
right:120px;
}
/*etc.......*/
```

Here is the a link to the JsFiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/wp6uLksw/

Comment: I see you are using jQuery but there is no link to the library in the head section. Pretty sure you mean six seconds by the way...

Comment: You have to update your fiddle. Your fiddle doesn't match the same code on stack overflow.

Comment: Agreed on both of the above comments. Also having trouble visualizing the effect you are trying to achieve based on the explanation, but maybe that is just me.

Comment: Updated the jsfiddle   I don't mean use jquery or link to a library those were the only script codes i could find would execute what I wanted. I'd like to only use script in the html since weebly makes it difficult to link to other code files @Shikkediel

Comment: Maybe try wrapping your scripts in a `$(document).ready(function() { ... })`. To be honest, still not sure if it's hooked up to the library.